# Picking a front-end/interpreter for a scientific code

Tags: c++, python, matlab, tcl, interpreter

The simulation tool I have developed over the past couple of years, is written in C++ and currently has a tcl interpreted front-end.  It was written such that it can be run either in an interactive shell, or by passing an input file.  Either way, the input file is written in tcl (with many additional simulation-specific commands I have added).  This allows for quite powerful input files (e.g.- when running monte-carlo sims, random distributions can be programmed as tcl procedures directly in the input file).

Unfortunately, I am finding that the tcl interpreter is becoming somewhat limited compared to what more modern interpreted languages have to offer, and its syntax seems a bit arcane.  Since the computational engine was written as a library with a c-compatible API, it should be straightforward to write alternative front-ends, and I am thinking of moving to a new interpreter, however I am having a bit of a time choosing (mostly because I don't have significant experience with many interpreted languages).  The options I have begun to explore are as follows:

**Remaining with tcl:**
Pros:
 - No need to change the existing code.
 - Existing input files stay the same.  (though I'd probably keep the tcl front end as an option)
 - Mature language with lots of community support.
Cons:
 - Feeling limited by the language syntax.
 - Getting complaints from users as to the difficulty of learning tcl.

**Python:**
Pros:
 - Modern interpreter, known to be quite efficient.
 - Large, active community.
 - Well known scientific and mathematical modules, such as scipy.
 - Commonly used in the academic Scientific/engineering community (typical users of my code)
Cons:
 - I've never used it and thus would take time to learn the language (this is also a pro, as I've been meaning to learn python for quite some time)
 - Strict formatting of the input files (indentation, etc..)

**Matlab:**
Pros:
 - Very power and widely used mathematical tool
 - Powerful built-in visualization/plotting.
 - Extensible, through community submitted code, as well as commercial toolboxes.
 - Many in science/engineering academia is familiar with and comfortable with matlab.
Cons:
 - Can not distribute as an executable- would need to be an add-on/toolbox.
 - Would require (?) the matlab compiler (which is pricy).
 - Requires Matlab, which is also pricy.

These pros and cons are what I've been able to come up with, though I have very little experience with interpreted languages in general.  I'd love to hear any thoughts on both the interpreters I've proposed here, if these pros/cons listed are legitimate, and any other interpreters I haven't thought of (e.g.- would php be appropriate for something like this?  lua?).  First hand experience with embedding an interpreter in your code is definitely a plus!

Comment: CoreMaster2? Sounds just like a code another department in my Company develops.

Comment: Nope, it is an academic flow through porous media simulator that is used mostly by grad-students and post-docs in the research group I am a part of.

Comment: I would not call Python "efficient". Python code is fairly inefficient, and number crunching is usually done by C code accessed via a Python API :) I still use though, because it's just too easy.

Comment: @Matthieu M.- I guess I should have clarified- it seems that Python has efficient modules for performing scientific calculations (I think that would be a fair assessment).

Comment: I never used it, but I've heard of scipy being recommended for number crunching so I suppose it is efficient. It just uses a Python API over a C-backend, but then that's why Python interoperability was developped.

Comment: In what way do you feel limited by the language syntax of Tcl? (And which version are you using?)

Comment: There's a pretty cogent and sober essay http://journal.dedasys.com/2010/03/30/where-tcl-and-tk-went-wrong by an "insider" that I found while looking for ways that people have coped with the Tcl scalability problem. I couldn't find such practicum but am interested in links if someone knows one.

Comment: @Donal Fellows- the primary issue we are running into is in developing some somewhat complex pre-processing in our input files.  Mainly we are trying to solve some PDEs as a part of the pre-processor.   While we have been successful in doing so in TCL, to some extent we are having to re-invent the wheel for things that are already implemented in interpreters like matlab and I have heard in python using tools like scipy.  Additionally with the user-base's familiarity with python and matlab, it would reduce the learning curve for using the simulator.

Comment: @MarkD: Sounds to me like your users would probably be happiest with matlab (or octave, given reso's answer).

Comment: "modern interpreter"? Python is no more (nor less) modern than Tcl.

Comment: @MarkD, could you please give me an update as to what you ended up doing?  I have a similar dilemma: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6495965/supporting-both-tcl-and-python

Comment: @Juan: I ended up going with Python.  Specifically, I am using boost::python to integrate the C++ code with a python interpreter.

Comment: Adding a little pro for Tcl and con for Python: Tcl handles embedding in a multithreaded environment (e.g. more than one interpreter running a script in parallel) far better than Python does, which is very limited due to its design.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was a strong Tcl/Tk proponent from pre-release, until I did a largish project with it and found how unmaintainable it is. Unfortunately, since prototypes are so easy in Tcl, you wind up with "one-off" scripts taking on lives of their own.

Having adopted Python in the last few months, I'm finding it to be all that Tcl promised and a whole lot more. As many a Python veteran can tell you, source indentation is a bother for the first hour at most and then it seems not a hindrance but affirmatively helpful. Incidentally Tcl's author, John Ousterhout was alternately praised and panned for writing a language that forced the [One True Brace Style](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Indent_style#Variant:_1TBS) on Tcl coders (I was 1TBS so it was fine by me).

The only Tcl constructs that aren't handled well by Python are arbitrary `eval "${prefix}${command} arg"` constructs that shouldn't be used in Tcl anyway but are and the `uplevel` type statements (which were a nice idea but made for some hairy code). Indeed, Python feels a little antagonistic to dynamic `eval` but I think that is a Good Thing. Unfortunately, I've yet to come along with a language that embraced its GUI as well as Tcl/Tk; Tkinter does the job in Python but it hurts.

I cannot speak to Matlab at all.

With a few months of Python under my belt, I'd almost certainly port any Tcl program that is in ongoing development to Python for purposes of sanity.

Comment: "With a few months of Python under my belt, I'd almost certainly port any Tcl program that is in ongoing development to Python..."  Is that an offer? ;)

In all seriousness, it looks like python has quite a bit to offer, and since we have a new post-doc joining that is quite familiar with it, it is looking quite attractive.  Thanks for sharing your perspective- it is definitely helpful!

Comment: As a counterpoint, I've worked with large commercial projects with Tcl and found it to be extremely maintainable and scalable. In my experience those two are more a factor of the programmer or team than the language.

Comment: I've been around the Tcl community for 15 years now and don't recall every hearing John Ousterhout panned for "writing a language that forced the One True Brace Style on Tcl coders" but maybe I just haven't been paying attention. Sure, some people don't like it, but any other style and it wouldn't be Tcl. It's a feature, not a bug.

Answer (score 3):

Have you considered using Octave?  From what I gather, it is nearly a drop-in replacement for much of matlab.  This might allow you to support matlab for those who have  it, and a free alternative for those who don't.  Since the "meat" of your program appears to be written in another language, the performance considerations seem to be not as important as providing an environment that has: plotting and visualization capabilities, is cross-platform, has a big user base, and in a language that nearly everyone in academia and/or involved with modelling fluid flow probably already knows.  Matlab/Octave can potentially have all of those.

Comment: I had such a terrible experience with octave (years and years ago) that I hadn't even thought of it.  Put that way, it definitely makes sense as an option.  I wonder how similar the API for extending octive is to that of Matlab?

Comment: HI Mark, I haven't used it in years either, and wasn't impressed when I originally used it.  I was working with an EE prof last week: he had a full electro-magnetic tomography code written purely in Octave and it ran very fast, and really got me thinking about having another look at it.  I don't know where Octave stands in terms of incorporating other languages the way matlab does with Mex, but some googling shows a bit of promise in that area.

Comment: Good to hear that it has come a long way in the past few years.. I'll definitely have to give it a try again.

Answer (score 0):

Well, unless there are any other suggestions, the final answer I have arrived at is to go with Python.

I seriously considered matlab/octave, but when reading the octave API and matlab API, they are different enough that I'd need to build separate interfaces for each (or get very creative with macros).  With python I end up with a single, easier to maintain codebase for the front end, and it is used by just about everyone we know.  Thanks for the tips/feedback everyone!